# Decomposition of human body after death

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, death

What causes decomposition of human body after death? [Here](http://www.aftermath.com/content/human-decomposition) it says autolysis, while [Here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexberezow/2013/11/05/which-bacteria-decompose-your-dead-bloated-body/#4ab599e9295a) it says that bacteria decompose the body. If bacteria decompose the body, why don't they do while we are living?

Answer (score 2):

Bacteria don't decompose the body while your alive (or even when your at the office)

Because your immune system keeps the population safe, by eating them.

Both autolysis and bacteria cause decomposition.

But there are 2 types of decomposition. The kind that keeps you from being able to be rescusitated happens within 5 minutes at room temp after death.
This is oncosis.

The kind where you smell like French cheese happens later, as the cells pop and disintegrate, and then get eaten by bacteria, which release stinky chemicals.